# What does Kant mean by object of the senses in relation to pure geometry?

Tags: epistemology, kant

In studying Kant I am running into a problem. Kant refers to pure geometry as only having objective reality under the condition that it refers only to objects of the senses (Prolegomena, Note I). If Kant is speaking of pure geometry, then he must be talking about a priori intuitions, but objects of the senses seem to imply the sensing of objects in the world, or at least their outer appearances, which is a posteriori. So which is it, a priori pure geometry, or a posteriori objects of the senses?

Comment: I was also confused by this when I read it many years ago. I eventually decided that he meant that geometry is about space, and space is how objects of the senses are related to one another.

Comment: The same productive imagination that synthesizes objects from the manifold of sensation in perception also synthesizes pure intuitions in geometry. As a result, the former conform to the latter and we get synthetic *a priori*. But it also means that geometric concepts that pure intuitions attach to can only apply to objects of experience, the sensible objects, and not, say, to noumena.

Comment: This is really numerous ardent kantian readers’ confusion which in its another more well known problem formulation is akin to *”is visual geometric epistem true and deepest a priori form of understanding of human mind/intelligence? If not, what else we should thank for*…

Answer (score 2):

Kant's theory of geometry, and mathematics generally, holds that these sciences proceed by constructing certain objects that instantiate general concepts. This construction, Kant thinks (the reasons are related to limitations of logic of his time, cf. Jakko Hintikka, *On Kant's notion of Intuition (Anschauung)* - this essay has some flaws, and has been widely discussed and criticized, but it shows how this feature of Kant's  theory of mathematics is probably a consequence of the insufficiency of Aristotelian logic to formalize even most proofs from Euclid's *Elements*), is mediated by **intuition**. However, this intuition isn't empirical intuition (which derives its content from sensation), but formal intuition (see B161 for the distinction between forms of intuition and formal intuitions), i.e. an intuition in which the unity of manifolds of space and time is given, which is nevertheless **sensible**. Without going into details about sensible  vs. intellectual intuition, and why human beings don't possess anything like intellectual intuition, space and time can be characterized as such because they constitute the pure, or formal, element of any intuition. Objects of our senses as such, if we abstract from more specific features relating to particular senses, are given in space and time. Because, however, we abstract from all content of the sensation (our senses being affected by the object that we are to perceive), these formal features, although sensible, don't constitute *a posterior* knowledge, and thus mathematics, pure and to some degree applied, is *a priori* and in fact presupposed by all experience (which constitutes the main argument of the *Transcendental Aesthetic*).